# Are the Alexander-Whitney and Eilenberg-Zilber maps homotopy inverse in arbitrary abelian categories?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a monoidal abelian category.  Let $A$ and $B$ be simplicial objects in $\mathcal{A}$, and let $N_\ast(-)$ denote the normalized chain complex functor.  Let
$$AW_{A,B}\colon N_\ast(A\otimes B)
\longrightarrow N_\ast(A)\otimes N_\ast(B)$$
and
$$ EZ_{A,B}\colon N_\ast(A)\otimes N_\ast(B)
\longrightarrow N_\ast(A\otimes B)$$
denote the Alexander-Whitney map
and the Eilenberg-Zilber map respectively.
Then on homology $AW_{A,B}$ and $EZ_{A,B}$ induce inverse isomorphisms.
On the chain level they satisfy
$$AW_{A,B}\circ EZ_{A,B} = Id_{N_\ast(A)\otimes N_\ast(B)}$$
and, at least in the case $\mathcal{A}=\mathrm{Ab}$,
$$EZ_{A,B}\circ AW_{A,B}\sim Id_{N_\ast(A\otimes B)}.$$
Here $\sim$ denotes chain homotopy.

> Is it true that $EZ_{A,B}\circ AW_{A,B}\sim Id_{N_\ast(A\otimes B)}$ for an arbitrary monoidal abelian category
>   $\mathcal{A}?$  If so, does the result appear in the literature, or can a proof be quickly reconstructed from the literature?

**Remark:** What is most important for me is to know (1) how general $\mathcal{A}$ can be in order for the answer to be "yes",
and to know (2) that there is a chain homotopy $EZ_{A,B}\circ AW_{A,B}\sim Id_{N_\ast(A\otimes B)}$, and not just that
$AW_{A,B}$ and $EZ_{A,B}$ induce inverse quasi-isomorphisms.

**Some more information:** In the case $\mathcal{A}=\mathrm{Ab}$, the definition of $AW_{A,B}$ and $EZ_{A,B}$ can be found in Definitions 29.7 of Peter May's book *[Simplicial objects in algebraic topology](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/Simp.djvu)* and on the 
nLab page [monoidal Dold-Kan correspondence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+Dold-Kan+correspondence).  The definitions are the same for an arbitrary choice of $\mathcal{A}.$
Corollary 29.10 of May's book proves 
$AW_{A,B}\circ EZ_{A,B} = Id_{N_\ast(A)\otimes N_\ast(B)}$ 
and $EZ_{A,B}\circ AW_{A,B}\sim Id_{N_\ast(A\otimes B)}$,
again in the case $\mathcal{A}=\mathrm{Ab}$.  Section 8.5 of Weibel's book *[An introduction to homological algebra](https://math.mit.edu/~hrm/18.906/weibel-homological-algebra.pdf)* proves that the Alexander-Whitney and Eilenberg-Zilber maps 
are inverse quasi-isomorphisms, this time for an arbitrary abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, and in a more general bisimplicial setting.
§1.2.3 in Lurie's *[Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf)*
shows that $AW_{A,B}$ is a quasi-isomorphism in a somewhat more general setting.  [Are there Alexander-Whitney and shuffle maps for Dold-Kan for abelian categories?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247334/are-there-alexander-whitney-and-shuffle-maps-for-dold-kan-for-abelian-categories) is a different mathoverflow question with a similar title to mine.

Comment: This is surely true assuming the correct hypotheses on $\mathcal{A}$, which I suspect are: additive category with retracts equipped with biadditive monoidal structure.  The key point to keep in mind is that the proofs that produce a chain homotopy $EZ\circ AW\sim Id$ actually show the existence of a *natural* chain homotopy, i.e., a collection of transformations $H_k\colon N(A\otimes B)_k\to N(A\otimes B)_{k+1}$ which are natural in $(A,B)$ ...

Comment: When $\mathcal{A}$ is abelian groups, this condition means that $H_k$ must have a formula of the form: $a\otimes b\mapsto \sum_{f,g} m_{f,g}\; (af)\otimes (ag)$, where $f,g\colon [k+1]\to [k]$ are simplicial operators (which I think of as acting on simplices from the right), and $m_{f,g}$ is an integer.  This is because you can classify natural transformations $A_k\otimes B_k\to A_{k+1}\otimes B_{k+1}$, and they all have this form ....

Comment: (The terms of the normalized complex are natural summands of these objects, split off by idempotents which can be written as linear combinations of simplicial operators, so there is a similar statement for natural transformations $N(A\otimes B)_k\to N(A\otimes B)_{k+1}$.)  So there is an explicit formula for abelian groups, but which clearly is meaingful in a general context, and very likely proves what you want ...

Comment: It would be nice if somebody with time on their hands would produce an explicit formula for $H_k$, I doubt it is very difficult.

Comment: @Charles Thanks very much for sketching this answer!