# Explicit chain homotopy for the Alexander-Whitney, Eilenberg-Zilber pair

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, abelian-categories

Let $A$ and $B$ be simplicial abelian groups, and let $N_\ast(-)$ denote the normalized chain complex functor.  Let
$$AW_{A,B}\colon N_\ast(A\otimes B)
\longrightarrow N_\ast(A)\otimes N_\ast(B)$$
and
$$ EZ_{A,B}\colon N_\ast(A)\otimes N_\ast(B)
\longrightarrow N_\ast(A\otimes B)$$
denote the Alexander-Whitney map
and the Eilenberg-Zilber map respectively.
Does anyone know of an explicit chain homotopy realizing 
$$EZ_{A,B}\circ AW_{A,B}\sim Id_{N_\ast(A\otimes B)}.$$

Motivation for its existence can be found in the comments of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303851/are-the-alexander-whitney-and-eilenberg-zilber-maps-homotopy-inverse-in-arbitrar).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have it in page 7 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110308.pdf).